# regex expression for selecting a value

Tags: regex, xml

I want to write a regexp formula for the below sip message that takes number:
    <   sip:callpark@as1sip1.com:5060;user=callpark;service=callpark;preason=park;paction=park;ptoken=150009;pautortrv=180;nt_server_host=47.168.105.100:5060 >

(Actually there are "<" and ">" signs in the message, but the site does not let me write)

For this case, I want to select ptoken value.. I wrote an expression such as: **ptoken=(.*);p** but it returns me **ptoken=150009;p**, I just need the number:**150009**

How do I write a regexp for this case?

PS: I write this for XML script..

Thanks,

I SOLVE THE PROBLEM BY USING TWO REGEX:
ereg assign_to="token" check_it="true" header="Refer-To:" regexp="(ptoken=([\d]*))" search_in="hdr"/

ereg assign_to="callParkToken" search_in="var" variable="token" check_it="true"   regexp="([\d].*)" /

Comment: You can include the angle brackets if you indent the code 4 spaces or wrap it in back-quotes

Comment: Thx for the answer, I try it but did not work.

Comment: Where are these `<` and `>` actually?

Comment: in the beginnig and at the end of the sip message: <sip:callpark@as1sip1.com:5060;user=callpark;service=callpark;preason=park;paction=park;ptoken=**150009**;pautortrv=180;nt_server_host=47.168.105.100:5060>

Comment: Can you add the bit of code which returns **ptoken=150009;p**. Or a similar bit of code to clarify what the answer should include.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex:

```
ptoken=(\d+)
# searches for ptoken= literally
# captures every digit found in the first group
```

Your wanted numbers are in the first group then. Take a look at [this demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tC1jB8/2). Depending on your actual needs, there could be better approaches (Xpath? as tagged as XML) though.

Comment: thx for your answer, actually stars should not be in there i updated my question and my original reg expression seems work in regex101.com however, it won't work.. other regex checker sites show me the output as: ptoken=150009;p Also, your suggestion won't work..

Comment: @yok: Updated the answer, no stars anymore. See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/tC1jB8/2

Comment: it returns ptoken=150009, i just need 150009

Comment: @yok: Please post your full code in your original question. You only need the first (`$1`) group from my regex.

Comment: <ereg assign_to="callParkToken" check_it="true" header="Refer-To:" regexp="ptoken=(.*);p" search_in="hdr"/>   @Jan

Comment: @yok: There is still your **old** regex in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=ptoken=)(.+?)(?=;)
```

It captures any character `(.+?)` before which is `ptoken=` and behind which is `;`

Comment: Did you even test your expression yourself? There are a couple of errors in there.

Comment: guys, regex101.com is wrong!!! according to regex101.com my original expression is OK https://regex101.com/  however, in reality it does not work..

Comment: you didn't say which language/parser are you using. javascript doesn't support it. ruby and php does.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ereg ... >` action has the `assign_to` parameter. In your case `assign_to="token"`. In fact, the parameter can receive several variable names. The first is assigned the whole string matching the regular expression, and the following are assigned the "capture groups" of the regular expression.

If your regexp is `ptoken=([\d]*)`, the whole match includes `ptoken` which is bad. The first capture group is `([\d]*)` which is the required value. Thus, use `<ereg regexp="ptoken=([\d]*)" assign_to="dummyvar,token" ..other parameters here.. >`.

Is it working?